# PHP background process without ignore_user_abort

Tags: php, apache, http

There is the situation: a regular Apache server, HTTP request via `file_get_contents()` from php with stream context with timeout set to a low value (5 seconds ie.). The time limit from the called php side is set to about 2 hours. The thing is, there is no call to `ignore_user_abort(true);`, and yet the process survives and keeps doing its job.

Now the question: **how is this possible?** My only idea is that `file_get_contents()` does not “inform” the remote that the request timed-out.

Additionaly, there is no output buffering or compression set up, and no script shutdown function registered.

Comment: Did you check the default settings in php.ini?

Comment: I did, the default settings is that ignore_user_abort is turned off. The same in httpd config.

Comment: The php doc says: `PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client. Simply using an echo statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see flush().`
So basically if file_get_contents is running and nothing is printed while it is running the process runs for the whole 2 hours.

Comment: @TobiasKun Thanks, that would explain it!